# error in eclipse when creating Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I try to develop android app. I download the ADT bundle from  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html . and I extraced it and the launch **eclipse.exe** .then `new > android application project.....`

But after finished the creating of project it shows under console

```
[2014-09-17 14:21:58 - appcompat_v7] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2014-09-17 14:22:04 - MyFirstApp] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2014-09-17 14:22:04 - firstAndroidApp] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2014-09-17 14:22:04 - appcompat_v7] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
```

there was an alert box heading with "error occurred during building" and body with "building workplace"
how i slove them.pleace help me.

Comment: *Try this :* RightCLick on Project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties

Comment: where is the project.is on ectipse menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods.

**Method1**:  Use create new project from existing source in Eclipse.

**Method2**:   Right Click Project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

**Method 3**: If the project already contains a file default.properties you can open that file and edit+save it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because the appcompat_v7 is not correctly loaded. Try restarting the eclipse and at the right bottom of the screen you see all the contents that are being loaded like sdk builder etc. wait it all the essentials are loaded.